# How to realize "group of" is plural or single?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, collective-nouns

This is my first time to rise question and I'm a newbie in English.

I have some question about "group of"

> 1. The group of students **is** going to Tainan tomorrow.
> 2. A group of students **show** an interest in being medical technologists.

How to realize the group means the plural or single?
It's confuse me.

Comment: I believe the answer to this will vary between those who speak US English and those who speak UK English. In the US, groups are generally referred to in the singular. But in the UK, they are often referred to in the plural. I'm assuming that this holds true for *the group* (and even *a group*) as well as for the more normal collective nouns—although I could be wrong. At least in US English, it would be more common to use the singular: *the group (of  . . .)* ***is*** and *a group (of  . . .)*  ***shows***. Regardless, the *(of  . . .)* phrase has no bearing on the subject-verb agreement.

Comment: Where did you get these examples?  Did you make them up yourself, or are they from a textbook or some other source?  Is the source from the US or the UK (or elsewhere)?

Comment: "Group" is a collective noun and can be either singular or plural, depending on whether you are reffering to every individual or item, or to the entire group as a whole. This is true for British English. In American English, however, the singular is more common.

Comment: Hi Andrew, These example are from Taiwan test central [http://www.taiwantestcentral.com/Grammar/Title.aspx?ID=297] that help to learn English. Thanks.

Comment: Hi user178049, Yes, it's. I can't distinguish the difference between plural and  singular easily. Thanks.